# How to uninstall gfortran compiler on MAC OSX 10.7

Tags: compiler-construction, gfortran

I installed gfortran 90 when I wanted gfortran 77, which is causing errors in configuring mpich, so as such I wanted to uninstall gfortran 90 from my computer, but deleting gfortran from usr/local/bin didn't really do anything. When I do gfortran -v I get an answer, when I want something like bash: command not found. How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you want to remove your Fortran compiler to 'fix' your issue with configuring mpich? Why not figure out what is wrong with your configuration and fix that?

Comment: I want to remove the compiler so I can start over and reinstall the fortran77 version. There might be a way to use the fortran90 version with mpich but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: gfortran can compile Fortran 77, 90, 95, and (to some degree) 03 code. Feel free to ignore it, but my advice is to figure out why mpich is not working and fix that, rather than eliminate a good compiler from your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From : http://www.webmo.net/support/fortran_osx.html

`Thus, to uninstall the package, run
      $ sudo rm -r /usr/local/gfortran /usr/local/bin/gfortran`

**Edit:** There also other methods, it apparently depends of the package you've installed to get it.

Comment: depending the installer package you used, I had gfortran-uninstall command installed also. Used that and done.