# How to uninstall gfortran on MacOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, uninstallation, gfortran

I followed the instructions given here [How to uninstall gfortran compiler on MAC OSX 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564543/how-to-uninstall-gfortran-compiler-on-mac-osx-10-7)
But when I try to install gfortran again, it tells me a version of gfortran already exists.

Comment: Sounds like a problem for Server Fault, I think :)

Comment: @GROVER. This is *not* a topic for Serverfault.

Comment: @Sven I stand corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *.plist*, and *.bom* files related to the previous **gfortran** installation need to be removed from `/private/var/db/receipts/`.

```
rm /private/var/db/receipts/com.gnu.gfortran.bom
rm /private/var/db/receipts/com.gnu.gfortran.plist
```

This is to be done after you have removed **gfortran** from `/usr/local/` and `/usr/local/bin/`.