# How do I fix `ld: unexpected token: !tapi-tbd-v3 file` with gfortran on my Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, fortran

I keep getting this error whenever I try and compile a .f90 file on my Mac Mojave (10.14)

> collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault: 11]
>   compilation terminated.
>   ld: unexpected token: !tapi-tbd-v3 file 
>   '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64

I've tried uninstalling Xcode and command line tools multiple times as well as created a symlink to the *tbd file so it doesn't require the tbd files anymore. I've also tried deleting gfortran from my laptop and reinstalling it again but it's still not working.

I don't really know how to go about fixing this problem and I'm also a beginner at this compiler/linker topic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to download the source for gfortran and compile it in your mac? You can also find dmg installers ready to use. I've found [this link](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS) after a quick search. The documentation on how the dmg are built may worth a look even if you decide to just use the provided dmg.

Comment: I've tried installing gfortran using the dmg, but I still keep getting the same error as above. I'm not entirely sure how to compile gfortran using the source. I tried uninstalling and installing gcc again (gfortran is a part of gcc?) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: you have to uninstall gfortran separately. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564543/how-to-uninstall-gfortran-compiler-on-mac-osx-10-7) to see how to uninstall it in mojave. For compiling gfortran from source, you must have gcc installed. Check [this link](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/blob/master/build_package.md) with instructions on how to compile and build your own dmg

Answer (score 0):

In case you installed gfortran via MacPorts, please uninstall it and install the xcode variant of the ld64 port:

```
sudo port install ld64 +ld64_xcode
```

After this, install gcc (version N) with `-s` to build it on your local machine:

```
sudo port install libgcc<N> libgcc
sudo port install -s gcc<N>
```

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with solutions not using MacPorts.

Answer (score 0):

After installing macports, the below 2 commands worked for me

```
sudo port -f activate ld64
sudo port install ld64 +ld64_xcode
```